# Setting position of the windows alert

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, alert

Here I report an example of my alert:

[image: http://oi60.tinypic.com/4lt8d2.jpg]

As you can see from the picture I can not bring my alert window above the taskbar.

This is the code that I set the poszione of the window:

```
public new void Show()
    {
        this.Left = Application.Current.MainWindow.Left + 
            Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualWidth - this.Width;
        this.Top = Application.Current.MainWindow.Top +
            Application.Current.MainWindow.ActualHeight - this.Height;

        this.Topmost = true;

        Application.Current.MainWindow.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, 
                (System.Threading.ThreadStart)delegate()
                {
                    base.Show();
                });
    }
```

Comment: In your screenshot, the alert is above the taskbar. What's the problem here?

Comment: The alert must be lightly above and the left-most.

Comment: @Herdo maybe "above" means on the Y-axis (i.e. op wants it to *not* overlap the taskbar), but I'm just guessing

Comment: Exactly Alex.
I do not want overlapping but above mean along the Y axis. Sorry for my english

Comment: Ok. So what is `this` in the method `Show`? A new window normally spawns with a small offset from top-left.

Comment: Yes, this is the method that to show in figure .

So how can I do to place it the screen depending on the task bar? I have to add something to fix the position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some useful info in **[SystemParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters(v=vs.110).aspx)** to locate the window correctly. Specifically you need to get the `SystemParameters.WorkArea.Bottom`. The code should be like this:

```
this.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Right - this.ActualWidth;
this.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Bottom - this.ActualHeight;
```

Comment: In this way my alert window drops below the screen. 
I have something like this: [link](http://oi61.tinypic.com/5kghv6.jpg)

Comment: @iamwill I've used this for some projects of mine. I guess that the ***Taskbar*** is automatically hidden? (it's just shown when you move mouse on the bottom edge of your screen?). If it's fixed, I don't think the offset is such large.

Comment: Also please use exactly the code I posted. From your image, I can see that the `Top` of the window is exactly at the `Bottom` of the WorkArea, that means the `ActualHeight` is **0**? That does not make much sense. In fact there may be some offset but it should be little (from my experience).

Comment: Perfect!!!Thanks King King!!! has covered the offset automatically 
I was wrong to enter your code